# Wrong point of origin reference

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm facing problem with wrong point of origin when multiple elements are added to an SVG.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sbc6ejeu/2/

I've added an SVG and associated path and couple of circles to it. They seem to correspond to the correct origin. However when I move the slider, I expect the circle of id=movingCicle (as mentioned in the code) to move along the green curve (line). I'm unable to start the initial
position of the circle to the same origin as other svg elements.

Also I observe that the range of the red circle is not same as the other elements or the SVG to which it is appended. For the 2nd and 3rd drop down options, the red cicle moves out of the graph when the slider is increased. I feel I'm missing out on something.

Appretiate any help on this.Thanks!

```
function initialize() {
  // Add circle data
  jsonCircles = [{
    "xAxis": 50,
    "yAxis": 154
  }, {
    "xAxis": 150,
    "yAxis": 154
  }];

  // Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
  var margin = {
    top: 30,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 50
  };
  width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right;
  height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  // Set the ranges
  x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]);
  y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

  // Define the axes
  xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(10);

  yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(7);

  valueLine = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d, i) {
      return x(i);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return y(d);
    });

  // Adds the svg canvas
  svg = d3.select("#graph")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .attr("id", "svg1")
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
      "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
}

function updateCirclePosition(i) {
  d3.select("#movingCircle").remove();

  svg.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", +i)
    .attr("cy", yValues[i])
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("id", "movingCircle")
    .style("fill", "red");
}

function addSvgElements() {
  // Add the valueline path.
  var path = svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("id", "lineId")
    .attr("d", valueLine(yValues));
}
```

Comment: It's quite difficult to understand what should happen when I move the slider - should it move the red dot to the right, or should it follow the green path or? What should it do?

Comment: @tiblu It should move along the green line. I've added this expected behavior to the description now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the function `updateCirclePosition`, the variable `i` contains the value of the budget, and `yValues[i]` is the corresponding revenue.

The corresponding coordinates in the chart can be found using `x` and `y` functions, therefore `x(i)` and `y(yValues[i])`  should be used to set the correct `cx` and `cy`:

```
svg.append("circle")
  .attr("cx", x(i))
  .attr("cy", y(yValues[i]))
```

updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sbc6ejeu/5/

Comment: Thanks for explaining the usage of function for assigning the values to cx & cy.